# AEM 6.5 PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, ssl, osgi, aem, keystore

I have been struggling with getting AEM instances to work with the certs/keys generated by a trusted source. I am following the `/libs/granite/security/content/sslConfig.html` wizard and AEM tells me everything is configured properly. I then try going to access my instance over https in my browser (incognito window) on my new port and my certificate is recognized by my browser. Finally I go to my replication agent on Author and update the configuration to use the same exact https URL/Port I just tested in my browser that worked minutes before and a simple test of that newly updated agent spits out the following error message:

```
Replication test failed
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have double checked the `ssl-service` and can see my cert/key is correctly installed there.
If anyone has an idea why the replication agent is acting this way and how to fix it I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a local cert? Look at the Transport tab, then choose Relaxed. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: that did the trick man thank you for your answer, that helped a lot.